# Objects are not valid as a React child. (Found: Date (India Standard Time)) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am using react calendar.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar

My code is looks like:

```
   class ListingProcess extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super();
            this.state = {
                location: {
                    startDate: '',
                    endDate: '',
                },
            this.handleStartDate = this.handleStartDate.bind(this);
            };

 handleStartDate(date){
        alert(date)
        var locationObj = this.state.location;
        locationObj.startDate = date;
        this.setState({location: locationObj})

    }


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.handleStartDate}
          value={this.state.location.startDate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

whenever i set the value of start date in the state is shows error on console

**ERROR IS:**
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Fri Sep 20 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Please help.

Comment: You wrote `this.handleStartDate = this.handleStartDate.bind(this);` inside of `this.state`, is that a typo?

Comment: Are you getting calendar on first render?

Comment: yes i am getting calendar on first render

Comment: This code is working fine. Are you using `this.state.location` anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes am using it

Comment: on First time i am getting the proper calendar view but after selecting date the view is disapper

Comment: So, please show us how you try to render it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you are trying to render the date directly. Somehow, you need to get the desired info from the date object. I'm using [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) as an example here.

Also, do not mutate your state directly as you do in your code in `handleStartDate` method. You should update your state as I do, not change it directly.

```
class ListingProcess extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      location: {
        startDate: "",
        endDate: ""
      }
    };
    this.handleStartDate = this.handleStartDate.bind(this);
  }

  handleStartDate(startDate) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      location: {
        ...state.location,
        startDate,
      }
    }));
  }

  printDate() {
    return <p>{this.state.location.startDate.toDateString()}</p>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Calendar
          onChange={this.handleStartDate}
          value={this.state.location.startDate}
        />
        {this.state.location.startDate && this.printDate()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```